# Nginx + Apache + Wordpress redirects to localhost/127.0.0.1

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, wordpress

Anyone know how to fix an issue with Nginx + Apache + Wordpress redirecting to localhost/127.0.0.1? I've tried a lot of different fixes, but none have worked for me.

I can go to http://domain.com/wp-admin just fine and use everything there normally. But if I try to go to http://domain.com it redirects to 127.0.0.1. Everything also works fine if I just run through Apache.

Here are the relevant portions of my nginx.conf:

```
server {                                
    listen 80;           
    server_name domain.com;      
    root /var/www/html/wordpress;       

    location / {                      
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }                                 

    location ~ \.php$ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080; 
    }                                                                 
}
```

Here are the relevant portions of my httpd.conf:

```
Listen *:8080

ServerName <ip>

<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerAdmin test@test
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/wordpress
    ServerName domain.com
</VirtualHost>
```

This is what my nginx log loks like:

```
<ip> - - [19/Jun/2012:22:35:35 +0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0
```

This is what my httpd log looks like:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Jun/2012:22:24:46 +0400] "GET /index.php HTTP/1.0" 301 - "-"
```

--

WordPress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL) both have same `http://domain.com`

Adding proxy_set_header Host $host; results in "This webpage has a redirect loop."

It also works if I use

```
location / {
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
}
```

but not with any try_files statements that fall through to other locations.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but as I come across...

```
 location ~ \.php$ {
```

It's not enough to proxy requests to WordPress. Basically, you should do it the other way around :

Send all static file requests to Nginx explicitly :

```
location ~ \.(css|js|ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|pdf)$ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
```

Then proxy the rest to Apache :

```
location / {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
}
```

Comment: didn't worked for me

Comment: @PekoChan sorry about that. I can't further comment because I don't use this setup anymore.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not a server issue

go to 
http://domain.com/wp-admin/options-general.php
after login into dashboard and make sure Site Address (URL) is same as WordPress Address (URL) .

Comment: I considered that. WordPress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL) both have same `http://domain.com`

Answer (score 0):

Please set `proxy_redirect off;` in your `location ~ \.php$` block. For more info, please check out the official documentation [proxy_redirect](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_redirect).