# Nginx as a proxy for Apache server running WordPress

Tags: nginx, apache-2.4, wordpress, 301-redirect

I am facing a similar problem as [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/400262/nginx-apache-wordpress-redirects-to-localhost-127-0-0-1) where I am using Nginx as a proxy for Apache server (Ubuntu) running WordPress. The internal links of the website all give 301 redirects to localhost.

For instance, the link: `wwww.example.com/internal-link` redirects to `localhost/internal-link` which gives error 404.

The **Apache** configurations are as follow:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        <Directory /var/www/html>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        ServerAdmin email@email.com
        ServerName example.com
        ServerAlias www.example.com
        ServerAlias *.example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
 ...
```

The **Nginx** configuration file is as follow:

```
server {
       # Where IP is server IP and example is the domain name
       listen       IP:80;
       server_name  static.example.com;

       location / {
           proxy_pass http://localhost:8480;
           proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
       }

}

server {
       listen       IP:80;
       server_name  example.com;
       rewrite      ^ $scheme://www.example.com$request_uri redirect;
}

server {
        listen       IP:80;            # your server's public IP address
        server_name  www.example.com;   # your domain name

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8020;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }
}
```

The `.htaccess` is the default generated by WordPress:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

here is some of the records for Apache's access log:

```
10.0.2.2 - - [15/Jul/2016:07:11:31 -0400] "GET /link/ HTTP/1.0" 301 335 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Cliqzbot/1.0 +http://cliqz.com/company/cliqzbot)"
10.0.2.2 - - [15/Jul/2016:07:08:02 -0400] "GET /link/ HTTP/1.0" 404 5396 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:21.0)
```

any idea what is causing this and how to fix it?

Comment: Is apache issuing the redirects or nginx? Please post your nginx configuration.

Comment: @EEAA how can I check if Apache is issuing the redirect? I don't have access to nginx configuration

Comment: The redirects should be logged in the apache access_log. You're likely going to need to change your nginx configuration for this to work, though.

Comment: Why are you using both Nginx and Apache? I run Nginx and PHP for Wordpress, Apache not required. What happens if you take away either Nginx or Apache? Nginx/Wordpress tutorial: https://www.photographerstechsupport.com/tutorials/hosting-wordpress-on-aws-tutorial-pt1-introduction-configuration-downloads/

Comment: Why did you bother adding a bounty before you answered all the outstanding questions? Someone might solve your exact question, but there may be a generally better setup that could help more.

Comment: @Tim what is exactly outstanding question? I answered all questions in comment. Your question "Why are you using both Nginx and Apache?" is not relevant because this is the environment I was forced to work with.

Comment: I was asking about the why. It would be useful to see a curl for a resource, and the corresponding entries in the Nginx and Apache logs. That will tell us where the 301 is coming from and will help narrow down how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I use following NGINX server block to `proxy_pass` all requests to local Apache HTTP Server:

```
# cat /usr/local/etc/nginx/conf.d/apache24.conf 
server  {
    listen 80;

    location    /   {
        proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1;
        proxy_set_header    Host    $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP   $remote_addr;
        proxy_pass_header   server;
    }
}
#
```

and Apache's HTTP Server `VirtualHost` configured normal way.

Comment: this should be placed instead of last server configuration in the file? I never worked with nginx so not sure

Comment: @RainMan I dont know how your environment setup, so I cannot tell you to replace anything there, but I would recommend you to make a backup before making any changes, but the idea is if you're using default `nginx.conf` and use `include conf.d/*.conf;` you can then place this into your `conf.d` and it should work)